# Zero populating array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I was trying to figure out how to populate an array with zeros and came across this solution that confused me.

```
col = 3
row = 3
A = [[0 for column in range(col)] for row in range(row)]
```

How come you can put a number next to a for loop and python will know to repeat that value within it? If I do:

```
0 for column in range(col)
```

outside of the list it comes out as an error. Why is this?

Also how does adding a for loop work here? I thought the for loop format was like this:

```
for value in Something:
     #Repeating code
```

Why doesn't the solution follow this for loop format? If I did a for loop not in this format outside the list it comes out as an error.

Comment: Reading [5.1.3. List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) from the official docs explain this quite well. [5.6 Looping techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) might also be a good thing to skim over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get an error with `0 for column in range(col)` is because this feature is known as a list comprehension and it's missing the `[]` "listness" :-)

What you would need is:

```
[0 for column in range(col)]
```

The basic idea is that `[value for <some iteration function>]` will give you a list of `value` items, as many as there are iterations of the iteration function.

And the reason that `for` works here is because it can be used in more than one way, in much the same way as you can use `break` within `for` or `while` loops, or `if` in list comprehensions as well:

```py
>>> [x for x in range(20)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

>>> [x for x in range(20) if x % 3 == 2]
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17]

>>> [x if x % 2 == 0 else -x * 100 for x in range(10)]
[0, -100, 2, -300, 4, -500, 6, -700, 8, -900]
```

Comment: Oh I see, so it's just a unique characteristic of working with lists. Would this work with things other than for loops?

Comment: @CKA, you would need something with a finite iteration count, I've never thought too much about it in all honestly. Given it's meant to be used with an iterable of some sort, I suspect `for` is the only way, though I don't discount the possibility of some dark corners of Python I don't know yet :-) I've added some code that shows you can use *extra* stuff, like an `if` filter.

Comment: Wow that's really interesting, thank you so much. Also just curious, if you can use an IF statement, could you also use an ELSE statement? I tried it in PyCharm and it doesn't seem like it's possible

Comment: @CKA: you can indeed use `else`, it's just a matter of re-ordering things (putting the `for` last). See my latest update.

Comment: Wow, absolutely blowing my mind here. Thanks again!